# Razor WebViewPage extension methods not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I'm trying to create extension methods for WebViewPage class to be able to call @Foo() in my .cshtml files.
And I'm almost sure that the following code should work but it doesn't...

I'm using System.Web.Mvc so I don't think it's a namespace problem either.

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc
{

    public static class WebViewPageExtensions
    { 

        public static void Foo(this System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage view)
        {
            //do something...
        }

    }
}
```

Note: I also tried to do this with a custom WebViewPage class, which worked, but I want to understand why I can't use extension methods.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a late answer, but you should be able to call @this.Foo() in your cshtml file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare your assembly for the webviewpages in the web.config?

```
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="YourAssembly, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </assemblies>
```

Comment: No, where should I put these lines ?
There is no <assemblies> block in my web.config, the only thing refering to assemblies is :

<controls>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
</controls>

Comment: should be: <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>

Comment: Doesn't change anything :/

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should create your own `WebViewPage`

```
 public abstract class MyWebViewPage : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage
    {

        public Foo F
        {
        //do something...

        }

    }
```

then add it to your `web.config`  in `<system.web.webPages.razor>` section :

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="[your custom webview class with namespace,ex: myproject.utiles.MyWebViewPage ]">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

then you can easily use @foo in all of your views